# Generate a dummy json by reading a json file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to generate dummy json by reading a json file in python. Is there a library in python which does this. Something similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/dummy-json.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Faker library for Python.

https://github.com/deepthawtz/faker

You can generate usernames, emails, names, numbers and a lot more.

Comment: The problem with faker is I can only do this if I know the fields. I want something with which I can supply the json and then the library can read and generate based on the values in the file,

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the type of contents you are willing to supply in that json file?

Comment: {
    "createdDate": "2016-01-28T20:59:40",
    "modifiedDate": "2016-01-28T20:59:40",
    "Id": "9a7a71fa-5258-4e88",
    "timeStamp": "2015-12-09T16:42:59.000Z",
    "data": {
        "value": 0.5750000000000001,
        "name" : "AL",
        "amf" : "random string "
    },
    "company": "ADASA"
}

Comment: So like this I have several jsons for which and they are multidimensional. So , I cannot go and read one key and change value, As there can be multiple keys inside one key and that I dont know as I will be given different jsons.